# Can I test a proportion (k success out of n) against an expected probability obtained from a logistic GLM?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, logistic

I have a logistic regression model which is obtained from literature about the probability of developing a toxicity ($y_{i}=1$ or $0$) when patients are given dose $X_{i}$. $X_{i}$ is a continuous variable. The model can be written as:

$Y_{i} \sim B(1,\pi_{i})$

$E(Y_{i})=\pi_{i}$ and $\operatorname{var}(Y_{i})=\pi_{i}(1-\pi_{i})$

$\operatorname{logit}(\pi_{i})=\alpha+\beta X_{i}$

and the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (and their confidence intervals) are known.

Now I have a sample of patients (from a different population than the model population) with known $X_{i}$ and $Y_{i}$. In general, I would like to test whether the new patient population behaves significantly different than model above.

One method that I can think of is to compare the sample's proportion of toxicity against the expected probability of toxicity computed from the model. Suppose that the proportion of toxicity in the sample is $\hat{\pi}$. Given $X_{i}, i=1,...n$ in the sample, I can compute the expected probability of toxicity as $\frac{\sum\pi_{i}}{n}$.

The null hypothesis is $H_0:\hat{\pi}=\frac{\sum\pi_{i}}{n}$

This equals a binomial test.

My questions are:

1) Assuming the model (excluding the confidence interval) from the literature is the ground truth, is this a proper test? Do I need to assume that each $X_{i}$ in the population has equal probability?

2) Or I should test $\hat{\pi}$ against the expected probability of toxicity from the theoretical model population? Given equal probability of $X_{i}$, thus equal probability of $\pi_{i}$, $E(\pi_{i})=0.5$, which sounds like I am comparing the sample proportion against 0.5, no matter what the model is.

3) Are there any other methods of comparing the patient population to the given model, e.g. hypothesis based on $\beta$?

Comment: First, the notation $E(Y_i = \pi_i)$ makes me think of the expectation of the indicator that $Y_i$ equals $\pi_i$. I think what you want is $E(Y_i) = \pi_i$ and analogously for the variance. Second, if the values of $\alpha,\beta$ are being treated as known, I don't see how a confidence interval comes in. Re: your actual question, I don't think testing whether the average predicted probability is the same in both samples gets at your question. Very different coefficient values could produce the same $\hat \pi$. The target of your inference should be the coefficients themselves.

Comment: Thanks @Macro for your reply. Testing on the coefficient is indeed the most straightforward way. The motivation for me to do this test is that in medical research, people are often interested in the expected occurrence (proportion) of toxicity $E(\pi_{i})$ in a patient cohort. That's why I come up with comparing the sample proportion against the sample expected proportion.

Comment: Suppose that I still would like to compare the expected proportion. Now I am doubting whether it is possible to conduct a statistical inference or not, because what I am comparing is just the expected sample proportion and the observed sample proportion. There is no inference to the population. That's why I proposed question 2 to test against the expected proportion over the population, which is always 0.5. Can you help me to get this concept clear? Thanks

Comment: The average you're computing is the expected occurrence, unconditional on (i.e. averaged over) the covariates. If that's all you're interested in, you don't need a model. The mean of the fitted values from a logistic regression will always exactly equal the sample proportion of ones in the data set. If that's all you want to test, then just do a two-sample test of proportions. I still don't see what this buys you. Based on your statement _"I would like to test whether the new patient population behaves significantly different than model above"_ it sounds like you want to compare coefficients.

Comment: Thanks @Macro. Your suggestion sounds like a chi-squared goodness of fit test.( note that I dont have the old sample from the model, what I have is only the mathematical model and the new sample). And you are right, comparing coefficient is the correct way to do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way of comparing coefficients is the following. Write $\alpha_0$ and $\beta_0$ for the known coefficients from the old sample, and let $n$ be the sample size in the new sample. As you do not have the old sample, $y_i, x_i$ refers to the new sample.

Let $A$ be a constant vector with all the components $\alpha_0$, and $B$ a vector with the values $\beta_0 x_i$.  Then, in R you can do

```r
mod0 <- glm(y ~ 0 + offset(A) + offset(B), family=binomial)
mod1 <- glm(y ~ x, family=binomial)
```

and fit statistics (a likelihood ratio test, assuming $\alpha_0, \beta_0$ as a gold standard) by

```r
anova(mod0, mod1, test="Chisq")
```

This is then really a chunk test for the two coefficients.

Taking into account the uncertainty in the old values $\alpha_0, \beta_0$  will be harder, having separate  confidence intervals will not be enough ... if you had a joint confidence region, you could maybe simulate somehow from that and repeat the procedure above.